# CDS year type / removing thousands separators from integer type

Tags: odata, sapui5, cds, sap-fiori

I want to display a column with years in my Fiori Elements List Report - Object Page. I tried to use the date format, but if you try to create a new entry you have to choose a day and month, as well. That should not be the case. Currently, I assigned the column the integer type, but that's causing the years to be formatted with a thousands separator (eg. 2,020 instead of 2020).

Can you provide a solution to this problem? Either by adjusting the date picker to just select a year or removing the thousands separator from the output? Or a different answer that fixes my issue.

**Edit:**
I found the `@Common.isCalendarYear` annotation but that annotation requires the corresponding field to be a string. So if I edit or create an entry in my Fiori Elements App I can enter any string I want (chars are allowed and the length is not limited to 4 except I define the field as String(4)). That should not be the case. Ideally, the app should use the date picker just with the year selection.

Comment: There is an answer to that question already: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58801799/9329965

Comment: @Greg Malewski But how do I implement that via annotations in my Fiori Elements application? The question you referenced is about the date picker control you would add in a custom/freestyle UI5 app.

Comment: @GregMalewski I agree

Comment: No, they imply different things. Fiori is the sap delivered suite of apps which has its own sets of problems, elements is the annotations driven variety of custom development that is a language on its own entirely, really. // replying to a comment I don’t see anymore now

Comment: @Jorg I generally agree. In SO, however, we should be careful not to create too many tags that it becomes difficult to manage and follow (if you're not a moderator). And since "Fiori Elements" is not a single product but part of SAP Fiori _design system_, I recommend to reuse the `sap-fiori` tag together with existing tags such as `odata` and `sapui5`.

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann There are no quality resources for annotation driven development, which is in part why I agreed elements needed a tag of its own. It might not be a single product but it is a single set of language elements that differs from the others