# Select only month and year on sap.m.Datepicker control Openui5

Tags: sapui5

I am using sap.m.Datepicker, On clicking of date icon a calendar is rendered showing current month and all dates.
Instead of showing dates, I only want to show up a calendar with months selection.

[Datepicker control showing month dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E60jG.png)

[Date picker showing months](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeLTW.png)
(this is what I am looking for, on click of date icon)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58802617/5846045

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to input only month and year in UI5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24242021/how-to-input-only-month-and-year-in-ui5)

Answer (score 3):

Previously with standard(version < 1.68) [`sap.m.Datepicker`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.DatePicker) its **not** possible to show only months with years.

**Update**: As of **SAP UI5 1.68**, DatePicker is capable of displaying the month-picker only. To enable it, displayFormat and valueFormat should be "MM/yyyy" and for only year "yyyy"

Comment: It's now possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58802617/5846045

Answer (score 0):

This can done by :

```
var oCalendar = new sap.ui.unified.CalendarMonthInterval({              
  width: "100%",
  select: this.handleCalendarSelect.bind(this),
}),
```